# Getting values from a table based on csv column

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table which contains columns with multiple values(comma separated).How to fetch data based on a single value from these columns.Using mysql as DBMS

Comment: Either normalise your data, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: Possibly find_in_set https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html